# Conflicting scroll functions causing delayed link clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I've got two functions for two different things.

For one, I'm getting smooth scroll for the anchor links on the page.

```
$(window).on("load",function () {
        // bind click event to all internal page anchors
        $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
                // prevent default action and bubbling
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                // set target to anchor's "href" attribute
                var target = $(this).attr('href');
                // scroll to each target
                $(target).velocity('scroll', {
                        duration: 700,
                        offset: -50,
                        easing: 'ease',
                });
        });
});
```

The other is for fading in the content when you scroll to it.

```
// fade all the sections
$(window).on("load",function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentPos = $(this).scrollTop()
    $(".section").each(function() {
            var topPos = $(this).offset().top - 500,
                    bottomPos = topPos + $(this).outerHeight();

      /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
      if (currentPos >= topPos && currentPos <= bottomPos) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
        $(this).fadeTo(700,1);
      }
    });
  }) //invoke scroll-handler on page-load
});
```

If I remove either one of these functions the entire thing will work fine. With both of them, they cause the page to have a huge delay in link clicks **only after** you've clicked down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Use css for the fade in instead of Jquery